# Algebraically Equivalent Fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let consider the ruled surface $X$ with morphism $\pi: X \to C$ to a curve.

Why then all fibers (of closed points) are as divisors algebraically equivalent?

Hartshorne explains it using an argument which isn't clear to me:

[image]

Why it suffice to be parametrised by curve $C$? Algebraically equivalent divisors have isomorphic invertible ideal sheaves on X, so why does the argument come from $C$?

Comment: What is your definition of algebraic equivalence ? It looks like you are talking about linear algebraic equivalence which is stronger.

Comment: The definition is: $D, D'$ are  equivalent if there exists a connected scheme $T$ with points $t_1,t_2\in T$ and a invertible sheaf $L$ on $X\times T$ so that $L|_{X\times t_1}\cong \mathcal{O}(D)$ and $L|_{X\times t_2}\cong\mathcal{O}(D')$. By the way: Of course, linear equivalence is stronger, but does it also hold for fibers?

Comment: Algebraic equivalence does not imply isomorphic invertible ideal sheaves. Any two points on a positive genus curve are algebraically equivalent, their ideal sheaves are not isomorphic.